# How to use threads to do two different tasks of printing numbers from 1-10

Tags: java, multithreading

I've seen many similar thread questions that are very helpful but I don't understand how to apply their answers to this problem.

I tried to create two threads to do two different tasks, instead, I've created two threads that do the same thing.

Expected output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Current output:

```
1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9
```

Code:

```
package midtermpractice;

public class PrintNums {

    public static class PrintRunnable implements Runnable {

        int num;

        public PrintRunnable(int x) {
            this.num = x;

        }

        synchronized public void run() {
            for (int i = this.num; i < 10; i++) {

                System.out.print(i + " ");

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.err.println(e);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread evenThread = new Thread(new PrintRunnable(1), "Even: ");
        Thread oddThread = new Thread(new PrintRunnable(2), "Odd: ");

        evenThread.start();
        oddThread.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and improve your question. All you've posted so far is a requirement, some not very helpful text, and a bit of unexplained code. If you want a decent answer, a little more effort into explaining your code, your current problem, where you're stuck, will go a long way towards getting one. Please read or re-read the [ask] for more on how to improve this.

Comment: actually there is not even a requirement posted... we can only imagine what the question could be... maybe it is just enough to change the increment to 2, like in `for (int i = this.num; i < 10; i += 2)`

Comment: Oops, sorry, sleep deprived. Edited and changed.

Comment: Why are you expecting your code to print out the correct result? Where do you force one thread to print only evens and where do you force the other to print only odds? You seem to be missing this most basic instruction, something much more basic than even threading itself.

Comment: Why would you expect this to do anything other than `1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 7 8 8 9 9 `? You have two threads printing numbers, one starting at `1` and one starting at `2`, both finishing at `10`.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to use `i += 2` instead of `i++`?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Where I've added (1) and (2) too the two threads , I expected the for loop to print print out the numbers 1,2,3,4 etc. Because if the numbers are already given as 1, the loop should count from there? But obviously I'm wrong, I thought that the loop would interchange between threads.

Comment: @oldCurmudgeon That prints out '2 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'

Comment: @LuiH - Perfect! Did you expect something else? Remember multithreading is all about code running in parallel with other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to output the list from 0 to 9, you will need to change some code. First, what you need to understand is:

> odd + 2 = odd
>
> even + 2 = even

I understood that you want a thread to print odd numbers and other to print even numbers. With that said, you need to change your code in a couple of lines.

```
for (int i = this.num; i <= 10; i+=2) {...}
```

and

```
Thread evenThread = new Thread(new PrintRunnable(0), "Even: ");
Thread oddThread = new Thread(new PrintRunnable(1), "Odd: ");
```